# How can export user with pwdchangedtime in openldap server to another openldap server

Tags: openldap, policyd

I am using openldap 2.4.42 version with policyd. I installed new version openldap server and I want export all user to new openldap. It's export is succussfull but without user password "pwdChangedTime". How can export user with pwdChangedTime in openldap server to another openldap server?

Answer (score 0):

How did you do the export? If you are moving your database from one server to another you should use `slapcat` to export the data on the old server and `slapadd` to import it on the new one. This way all attributes (including operational ones) will be included.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I used slapcat and slapadd for export. But the new ldap server service did not work. I found several resources on the Internet on this topic. I think I was confused while doing export operations. Could you share the slapcat and slapadd commands and steps.